# How to do a code in php and have text before it?

Tags: php, code

So I have this code: `the_title()`
And I am trying to add some text before it. So, it would end up like this:
PAGE TITLE: (page tile) => PAGE TITLE is what I am trying to add before my code. However, whenever I do that, the code pastes as plain text, like this:
PAGE TITLE: the_title().

I tried using echo before everything, but it is not working! Help, please?

Answer (score 3):

In order for the server to recognize and execute PHP code, the code must be enclosed within `<?php ?>` tags.

The first argument of [the `the_title()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) is a string that will be output before the page title itself, so

```
<?php the_title('Page title: '); ?>
```

will print something like

```
Page title: Just Another Post
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions with additional questions :) . If you believe you have a solution, state it as such. If you need further clarification on the original issue, post a comment on the original question. Additionally, your answer is likely to receive more positive attention if you elaborate on it - especially when the solution isn't so intuitive as is the case here. Why does the code you posted accomplish the desired outcome? Please review the "[answer]" page in our [help]